# Azure Sentinel (KQL)

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, azure-sentinel, microsoft365-defender, azure-defender

I'm looking for a KQL query to transform data from the query:

> EmailEvents | where EmailDirection=="Inbound"

such that the sample results (below) are transformed into the ideal results (further below)

Sample results:

```
TimeGenerated [UTC]      -      EmailActionPolicy
4/24/2023, 10:55:47:00          Anti-Phishing
4/24/2023, 10:55:48:00          Anti-Phishing
4/24/2023, 10:55:49:00          Anti-Phishing graph impersonation
4/24/2023, 10:55:50:00          Anti-Phishing
4/24/2023, 10:55:52:00          Anti-Phishing graph impersonation
4/24/2023, 10:55:52:00          Anti-Phishing Spoof
```

Ideal Results:

```
Date               Anti-Phishing    Anti-Phishing Spoof   Anti-Phishing graph impersonation   
4/24/2023          0                11                    75                                    
4/23/2023          55               24                    42
4/22/2023          25               44                    86
4/21/2023          23               22                    32
4/20/2023          8                67                    53
```

So the idea is to transform the data into a daily view of the count of each of these results for a specific field

Any help would appreciated - if there are any more conventional ways to format the ideal results, I would also be interested. Many thanks

Comment: chat gpt gave the following answer, but when executing, pivot is an invalid operation:

EmailEvents
| where EmailDirection == "Inbound"
| summarize count() by bin(TimeGenerated, 1d), EmailActionPolicy
| pivot EmailActionPolicy, sum(count_)
| extend Date = format_datetime(TimeGenerated, 'yyyy-MM-dd')
| project Date, *

Comment: the following gets very close, but does not give a view of the distinct email action policies  in columns 

EmailEvents
| where EmailDirection == "Inbound"
| summarize count() by bin(TimeGenerated, 1d), EmailActionPolicy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try using the [`pivot plugin`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/pivotplugin).

for example:

```
EmailEvents
| where EmailDirection == "Inbound"
| summarize count() by EmailActionPolicy, startofday(TimeGenerated)
| evaluate pivot(EmailActionPolicy, sum(count_))
```